# Numpy Polynomial Regression, error arising at higher powers

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code for finding the coefficients for polynomial regression,

```
x =[-1,0,1,2,3,5,7,9,4,6,8,2,4,6,8,5,2]
y = [-1,3,2.5,5,4,2,5,4,4,7,3,2,7,9,6,2,6]
degree = 4
x = np.asarray(x)
x = np.vstack((np.ones(len(x)),x))
i = 2
for p in range(degree-1):
    xs= np.power(x,i)
    x = np.vstack((x,xs))
    i +=1
y = np.asarray(y)
y= np.matrix(y).T
x= np.matrix(x).T
parameters =(x.T*x).I*x.T*y
```

this code will work for lower powers but begins to return different results as **`numpy.polyfit( x, y, degree )`** at around 16th degree.

Is my code incorrect, why does its result differ at higher powers to the built in function.

Comment: What's your question? This is not the right site to report numpy bugs.

Comment: sorry, I'm not reporting a numpy bug but rather where is my code incorrect that means it differs from the built in function, i have added my post to reflect this

Comment: The source code is available. You should also consider editing an actual question into your question.

Comment: Probably because you are not normalizing your x-axis to the domain -1 to +1 for numerical stability.

Comment: i reran my code with normalizing between -1 to +1 and am still getting inaccurate results, but thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Can you show how you did the normalization? Because that is the biggest trick in the numpy function for achieving numerical stability. I remember having the same problem for a fitting function I was writing, and the normalization pretty much fixed everything if I recall correctly.

Comment: norm = 2*(x - np.max(x))/-np.ptp(x)-1, was the code i used, keeping the domain between 0-1 allowed the code to still work at lower powers but putting the domain between -1,1 broke the results at lower powers too.

Comment: Actually, i rechecked my metrics, normalization does improve the accuracy at higher powers, Its still not outputting the perfect result at the n-1 degree as expected but it starts to break at a later degree than before, but thank you for your help i understand where it goes wrong now. i appreciate your time and help

Answer (score 0):

Given `n` data points, you can only fit up to degree `n - 1`, after that there is insufficient data to determine a unique polynomial. Effectively, you are dividing by zero.